# Raffle percentages

Tags: probability

I am attempting to determine if there is a value percentage for purchasing chances in a raffle.

For instance there is a $\$200$ prize and $20$ Raffle Tickets total, each costing $\$10$.  If I buy $2$ raffle tickets, my cost is $\$20$, and I have a $10\%$ chance of winning.

Is there a way to calculate the best value versus cost?  For instance am I better off buying $5$ tickets or just $1$?  Obviously buying more tickets increases my odds, but reduces my value.

Comment: This game has $0$ expected return.  Doesn't matter if you buy $0$ or all $20$, from the viewpoint of straight expectation.  Of course, you might have a different utility function.

Comment: Side note as to formatting:  the reason your text looked so garbled was that the mathematical compiler used by the site, LateX, interprets the dollar sign as code.  If you click on "edit" you can see the syntax I used to get it to display the dollar sign in the usual way..

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you are better off buying none.  In this case, you could also buy all of them for the same return since you would have 100% chance of winning 100% of your money back.

In general, your expected value is $E = \sum_{i=0}^n p_i (W_i-c) + (1- \sum_{i=0}^n p_i)(0-c)$

where $W_i$ is a prize, $c$ is the ticket cost.

For example, at a raffle, 10,000 tickets are sold at \$5 each for three prizes valued at
\$4,800, \$1,200, and $400. What is the expected value of one ticket?

$E = \frac {1} {10,000} (4800-5) + \frac {1} {10,000} (1200-5)+ \frac {1} {10,000} (400-5) + \frac {9.997} {10,000} (0-5) = -4.36$

This means that, on average (i.e., if you played this an infinite number of times), you will lose \$4.36  on every ticket you buy.